# CakePHP - downloading file

Tags: php, cakephp, download, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I used the following code for downloading a file

```
    public function sendFile($filePath,$filename) {             
    $this->response->file($filePath, array('download' => true, 'name' => $filename));
    return $this->response;
    }

function download($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $upload = $this->Upload->findById($id);
    if (!$upload) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid id for upload', true));
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
    $filename = $upload['Upload']['filename'];
    $filePath = APP.'uploads'.DS.$id.DS;
    $this->sendFile($filePath,$filename);
}
```

but I got the following notice and error

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: UploadsController::$response
Fatal error: Call to a member function file() on a non-object
```

I've googled it a lot to solve it but nothing worked.

Comment: what does your complete controller look like? seems like its not a valid and real controller you got there. also note that what you are doing there is quite dangerous. You should not make it possible to let people insert paths here via url. This can be a huge security flaw!

Comment: I've edited the code that has the real controller and as you can see I didn't take the path from user input. Thanks for this advise.

Comment: it should not be a public (and therefore accessable via frontend) method in your controller. either use components or make it protected would be my advice. Are you sure you are using cakephp 2.x? looks more like 1.x code to me.

Comment: Thanks Mark, You're right, I was using cakephp 1.x, should I read the 2.x book before coding or do you have a good reference for learning coding with cake in a limited time?

Comment: also, there is no need to return `return $this->response;`. You can just set `$this->autoRender = false;`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use download method in controller

see link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html

Comment: As of version 2.3, MediaView is deprecated and you can use CakeResponse::file() to send a file as response (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files)